# How to access individual properties in an array of objects returned from axios post?

Tags: javascript, axios, properties

I am trying to search a database for records on specific workout data to use Chart.js to display a line graph showing progress. I have the data returned from Axios, but when trying to use `chart.js`, it gives me an error saying I can't use an array of objects as input for chart, so I need to access the individual properties of each object to create an array for the `x` and `y` axis.

What would be the syntax for accessing each `date` and `weightOne` from all objects?

One of the 14 objects returned from axios post:
[image]

I have tried accessing the properties from the axios response in a loop and adding each date and WeightOne to an array, but the arrays are still empty.

[image]

This is the code I have, but it only returns two empty arrays:

[image]

Comment: Put your code and expected results into text

Comment: If that's an Array of Objects, then you can `.map` over this Array and use *dot notations* to access `item.date` and `item.weightOne`

Comment: @Aleksandar i have added the code and expected results. I thought this would work in creating two arrays, but they are still empty.

Comment: @Aleksandar do you have any ideas about how to solve this?